# Error installing pandas for python 3.7.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, virtualenv

**Context:**

I am using the brand new MacBook pro with M1 pro, it has macOS Monterey 12.0 it is only has a week old.

I installed `pyenv` with brew and then I installed version 3.7.12, I wanted to create a `venv` and install pandas inside it but by mistake, I started to install it on the `pyenv` of the 3.7.12 without the `venv` created. When it was executing the installation and I realized I pressed Command + C and stopped.

After that, I created the `venv` "cosa5" and try to install it but it showed me the following error:

```
(cosa5) matiasnavarrete@MacBook-Pro-de-Matias codetest % pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.4.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/bin/python /Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-44pq47ee/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.24,<3' 'oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
    Using cached setuptools-59.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (979 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-0.12-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.14.5; python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    Using cached numpy-1.14.5.zip (4.9 MB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-install-r3mgeudj/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-install-r3mgeudj/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-h4uqe4mm
           cwd: /private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-install-r3mgeudj/numpy/
      Complete output (11 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "/Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
          from setuptools import windows_support
        File "/Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/Users/matiasnavarrete/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/bin/python /Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/4p/syttjfhj7896l__s3gtxnxkm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-44pq47ee/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.24,<3' 'oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/matiasnavarrete/Desktop/codetest/cosa5/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I don't know if the fact that I stopped it is related to the bug or not, but I mentioned it anyway.

Tried uninstalling 3.7.12 from `pyenv`, installing it again, creating a new `venv` but it keeps showing the same error.

After this I installed 3.9.9, I created the `venv` and I installed pandas and I had no problem with that version. It is 3.7.12 that keeps giving me problems.

**Question:**
How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you specifically need Python 3.7.12?

Comment: Just because I was trying pyenv and enviroments trying to learn how to use different versions, but turns out I broke it. There must be a way to fix it